# Not getting all the available Remarketing Audience through the Google Analytics Services API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

We have below Remarketing Audience in our Google Analytics Account:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UQIP.png)

Further, we are trying to fetch this list of Audiences through the below provided Google APIs (PHP)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/list
The above API is giving us back only two records which are having 'Adwords' in their "Type". Our concern is to fetch all the records available in the list.

We have also checked the result through the provided console of the Google but it is also giving us back only two records:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.remarketingAudience.list

Does anyone know what may be the issue?